# SwiftUI: how to add padding to the first item in VStack

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a VStack with a list of items. I noticed that there's no padding for the first item. But there's padding for the gaps between each items. I am wondering how I can put a padding on the top.

[image]

The code looks like this:

```
VStack {
  item1
  item2
  item3
  Spacer()
}
```

I have tried to add a padding() on the top of VStack, but I got hang'ed without error message:

```
VStack {
  padding()
  item1
  item2
  item3
  Spacer()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.padding()`adds padding to the view it is attached to (and it has to be attached to one, it can't stand alone).

what you want is a padding on the VStack:

```
VStack {
    item1
    item2
    item3
}
.padding()
```

or

```
.padding(.top)
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need any kind of padding if you used a `NavigationView` then a `NavigationLink` in a `List`. Example below.

[image: link]

```swift
struct BillsView: View {
    @State var name: String = ""
    @State var value: Double = 0.0
    var body: some View {
        List {
            TextField(text: $name, prompt: Text("Bill amount")) {
                Text("Bill Amount")
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Tip")
                Spacer()
                Slider(value: $value, in: 1...10)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Bills", displayMode: .inline)
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: BillsView()) {
                    Text("Navigation link here")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Example", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```